# Is there a standard way to route a setState redux action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to create a general setState action in many react-redux reducers so that I can use the same syntax for dispatching state updates locally and in redux scope. I would call on `this.setState` for local updates and `this.props.setState` for redux updates.

The reducer case looks like this:

```
case "SET_STATE": 
   return {...state, ...action.payload}
```

This works great for one reducer, but if I have many reducers via `combineReducers`, it sends the `setState` action to all of them. That's not the behavior I want. I need to route my setState action to the reducer it was meant for. I am wondering if react-redux has a standard recommended way of doing this, or if this is beyond their built in functionality?

Comment: Have you looked at [HOC reducer](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic) pattern ?

Comment: You should have your state only in one place at a time, **redux** to persist it when component is unmounted and to access it throughout the whole app, and, **react state** for a state related only to that specific component. If you have your state duplicated, it will be hard for you too keep it in sync and it will lead to bugs

Comment: @victor.ja I don't have my state duplicated.

Comment: @abadalyan that's exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reuse the same logic across several reducers you might find higher-order reducer pattern helpful.

For instance, let's say your reducer logic looks like this:

```
function setState(state, action) {
   switch(action.type) {
      case "SET_STATE": 
         return {...state, ...action.payload}
      default:
         return state
   }
}
```

You can reuse it in several slice reducers by creating higher order reducer:

```
function createNamedWrapperReducer(reducerFunction, reducerName) {
  return (state, action) => {
    const { name } = action
    const isInitializationCall = state === undefined
    if (name !== reducerName && !isInitializationCall) return state

    return reducerFunction(state, action)
  }
}
```

Use it to create slice reducers and combine them with `combineReducers`:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  setStateA: createNamedWrapperReducer(counter, 'A'),
  setStateB: createNamedWrapperReducer(counter, 'B'),
  setStateC: createNamedWrapperReducer(counter, 'C')
})
```

The action creator might looks like this:

```
setStateAction(name, payload) {
   return {
      type: "SET_STATE",
      name,
      payload
   }
}
```

Checkout [Reusing Reducer Logic](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic) for more details and examples.